# Capping the amount of a certain cost per route with Network Analyst

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, routing, network, cost-path

With the Network Analyst extension in ArcGIS 10.2, is there a way to set the maximum amount of a certain cost that a route must not exceed? For example, can I require routes to be below a certain length? Or, if a route makes several stops incurring some cost (i.e. picking up some packages or containers) at each stop, can I route it such as not to exceed the number of items picked up for all stops it visits?

Comment: That depends on the solver you are using. You can cap distance if you are using a Service Area solver. You can cap based on an incurred cost like packages and such if you are using a Vehicle Routing Problem (VRP) solver. So any answer depends on what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: I will be doing this with VRP in Network Analyst.

Comment: I would suggest reviewing the help file for that solver: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00470000004v000000 In particular the Delivery/PickupQuantities, maxtotaltime, maxtotaldistance, cumuldistance, and cumultime parameters. Some of these are properties of the solver, and some are attributes of the 'orders'.